# Helicopter controller, spherical world with faux gravity

Tags: unity

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHeQ8Hr92P4&t=601s) to create a planet with faux gravity that attracts objects.

Further I'm trying to create a helicopter-like controller that could move vertically and horizontally and that when the player presses control buttons this would compensate the faux gravity applied with `AddForce` to `Rigidbody` and the helicopter could fly. I implemented that in a way that when player presses buttons faux gravity with `AddForce` is not applied, but still the control feels very awkward.

What would be the best way to compensate the faux gravity to move the helicopter?

Edit: I only need it to move in XY plane (so only up/down/left/right). The camera looks on helicopter from its right side. The attractor script works in 3 axis and this is ok for now.

Player controller (assigned to the helicopter):

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed = 15;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private Vector3 moveDir;
    private float h;
    private float v;

    void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if(!rb) throw new Exception("Game Object must have Rigidbody!");
    }

    void Update () {
        GetControls();
        moveDir = new Vector3(h, v, 0).normalized;
    }

    void GetControls() {
        h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDir) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Faux Gravity Attractor (assigned to the planet):

```cs
public class FauxGravityAttractor : MonoBehaviour {
    public float gravity = -10;

    public void Attract(Transform body) {
        Vector3 gravityUp = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;

        Vector3 bodyUp = body.up;

        Rigidbody bodyRb = body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        bodyRb.AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyUp, gravityUp) * body.rotation;
        body.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(body.rotation, targetRotation, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Faux Gravity Body (assigned to the helicopter):

```cs
public class FauxGravityBody : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    float gravity = -10;

    public FauxGravityAttractor attractor;
    private Transform myTransform;

    void Start () {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        rb.useGravity = false;
        myTransform = transform;
    }

    void Update () {
        attractor.Attract(myTransform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about how you're moving your helicopter now, what about it currently feels "awkward," and how you'd like it to behave instead?

Comment: I extended my question with code examples.

Comment: This is not a bad question, just a pity you never followed up on Robin's response or gave further indication of your progress. Perhaps you could do so, or provide your own answer if you solved it on your own?

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer, I've accepted his answer, thanks for pointing this out. When I worked on the project in July I didn't manage to make that work. Now having slightly more experience, I think his answer is valid although unfortunately I have no time to check that since working on something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tutorial also rotates the character based on it's relation to the planet, you can use [AddRelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) to move the helicopter up.

If you didn't fully understand the tutorial, I would recommend reading [these articles](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/). Linear algebra is a very useful skill in game development and, since Unity does all the difficult stuff for you, it's pretty simple.